# Summing records in VBA Collection

Tags: linq, excel, vba

I have a VBA collection consisting of DayTots class objects (see below)

I am using a For Each to iterate thru the collection to create a 
new collection consisting of summed records, based on Date

Is there some way I could do this with Linq?  I suspect maybe I could replace 
several lines of code with something much simpler and more straightforward
using a Linq query (maybe using a Group?)

I couldn't find anything on the internet that seemed to address this situation

Thanks in advance for all assistance

input collection

```
tDate       TotTrav TotTrav TotParts
            Yes     No      Accepted
2/27/2017   1       0       1
2/27/2017   1       0       0
2/27/2017   1       0       0
2/27/2017   0       1       0
2/28/2017   1       0       1
2/28/2017   0       1       0 
2/28/2017   0       0       1
```

output collection

```
DatDate     TotTrav TotTrav TotParts
            Yes     No      Accepted
2/27/2017   3       1       1
2/28/2017   1       1       2

Dim cumRecs As DayTots   
dim incoll, outcoll as Collection

outcoll = New Collection

For Each irec In incoll
    ....
    outcoll.Add(cumRecs)
Next irec

'Class DayTots

Dim DatDate              As Date
Dim TravYes              As Integer
Dim TravNo               As Integer
Dim PartsAccepted        As Integer

Public Property Get tDayDate() As Date
    tDayDate = DatDate
End Property

Public Property Let tDayDate(value As Date)
    DatDate = value
    Weekno = Int(((DatDate - DateSerial(Year(DatDate), 1, 0)) + 6) / 7)
End Property

Public Property Get TotTravYes() As Integer
    TotTravYes = TravYes
End Property

Public Property Let TotTravYes(value As Integer)
    TravYes = value
End Property

Public Property Get TotTravNo() As Integer
    TotTravNo = TravNo
End Property

Public Property Let TotTravNo(value As Integer)
    TravNo = value
End Property

Public Property Get TotPartsAccepted() As Integer
    TotPartsAccepted = PartsAccepted
End Property

Public Property Let TotPartsAccepted(value As Integer)
    PartsAccepted = value
End Property
```

Comment: Linq does not exist in VBA/Office, so, nope.

Answer (score 0):

What you are hoping for can be achieved with `Array` and `WorksheetFunction.Sum` Here is a small example:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim inColl  As New Collection
    Dim inArr   As Variant

    inColl.Add 1
    inColl.Add 2
    inColl.Add 3
    Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Sum(inColl.Item(1), inColl.Item(2), inColl.Item(3))

    inArr = Array(5, 6, 7, 8)
    Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Sum(inArr)

End Sub
```

The result in the immediate window is `6` and `26`. In general, it is not difficult to convert collection to array.

Comment: Thank you.  That gets me closer.  But is there a way to do the summing restricted to those entries that match a key?